# Applying nlargest to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I am struggling with `pandas`.

I am running a simulation, where N is the number of simulations. At the end of the simulation, I have a `DataFrame` of N*2 + 2 columns. The first column is Date, the first N are temperature simulations, the second N columns are consumptions calculated based on these temperatures and the last is the mean consumption column.

What I would like is to, and only for the consumption columns deduced from the temperature simulations- without the mean consumption column, get the n (let's say n = 10) largest values for each column independantly and replace these n largest values with 1/n. For one column it is easy since I can do:

```
df.iloc[df.nlargest(n, df.columns[N]).index, N] = 1/n
```

I want to do this however for multiple columns. I tried using `.apply`, but it didn't work. I do not want to use a for loop since N can be 100 000 or more.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `where` on the descending [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) for the consumption columns, try

```
# example data
np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_':pd.date_range('2021-05-20', periods=10), 
                   'T1':range(20,30), 'T2':range(30,40), 
                   'C1':np.random.randint(10,100, 10), 
                   'C2':np.random.randint(10,100, 10),})
df['C_mean'] = df[['C1','C2']].mean(axis=1)

# number of experiments
N = 2
cols_ = df.columns[N+1:-1] 
# define the number to replace
n = 4
# replace the values
df[cols_] = df[cols_].where(lambda x: x.rank(method='first', ascending=False)>n, 1/n)

print(df)
       date_  T1  T2     C1     C2  C_mean
0 2021-05-20  20  30  50.00   0.25    67.5
1 2021-05-21  21  31  25.00   0.25    60.0
2 2021-05-22  22  32   0.25  57.00    69.5
3 2021-05-23  23  33  32.00   0.25    52.5
4 2021-05-24  24  34  53.00  41.00    47.0
5 2021-05-25  25  35   0.25  30.00    61.0
6 2021-05-26  26  36   0.25  47.00    66.0
7 2021-05-27  27  37  17.00  49.00    33.0
8 2021-05-28  28  38  44.00   0.25    60.5
9 2021-05-29  29  39   0.25  14.00    36.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your data are homogeneous, you can see your dataframe as a numpy array with `to_numpy`. Then you can try `np.argsort`, which is a bit more expensive than `nlargest`, but it can handle several columns at once:

```
# toys data
N,n = 4,5

np.random.seed(43)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(10,2*N+2)))

arr = df.iloc[:,N:2*N].to_numpy()

s = np.argsort(arr, axis=0)[-n:]

arr[s,np.arange(N)] = -1
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  4  0  1  5  0  3  1  2  7  0
1  3  2  9  1  2  2  3 -1  4  4
2  0  5  8  0  0 -1  2  0  4  4
3  8  9  7  4 -1 -1  0  3  2  9
4  9  0  6  5  5 -1 -1 -1  3  6
5  3  2  4  2 -1  3 -1 -1  3  6
6  7  4  5  3 -1  3 -1  3  5  1
7  6  0  0  7  1  3  1 -1  8  0
8  3  6  9  4 -1 -1 -1  4  5  8
9  4  7  4  2 -1 -1 -1 -1  8  1
```

Comment: both answers are correct but the second is better for me since i want to stay in pandas